# Tell LLDB to ignore files

Tags: c++, lldb

Is there a way to tell LLDB to ignore a file, i.e. step over code in that file when debugging?

(This could be used as a workaround for [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439318/debug-issues-with-libc-in-xcode-4-4), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651441/debugger-steps-deeper-when-trying-to-step-out-of-c11-std-lib), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099916/stepping-through-the-code-is-stopping-on-stl-code-when-debugging-c-with-xcode?lq=1))

Answer (score 8):

There is a setting to avoid stepping into functions whose name match a regular expression,

```
(lldb) set list target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp
step-avoid-regexp -- A regular expression defining functions step-in won't stop in.
```

e.g. put this in your `~/.lldbinit` file

```
settings set target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp ^[^ ]+ std::|^std::
```

but in Xcode 4.5.x that's the best that can be done.  I mentioned in #2 of your links that inlined stepping support has been added to the LLDB sources at http://lldb.llvm.org/ but that won't be in Xcode until the next release.

Comment: did you test that? Doesn't seem to do anything for me. also the backtrace doesn't even show the std functions after it stepped in there.

Comment: Also, which version of Xcode / lldb will include the changes you mentioned? I'm using Xcode 4.6 and my lldb identifies as `LLDB-173`.

Comment: yeah, I should have been clearer -- the step-avoid-regexp will only work for out-of-lined functions (i.e. not inlined functions) and the real problem here is that the C++11 std library forces many of its methods to be inlined even when compiled at -O0.  I don't have any comment regarding pre-release/seed/unreleased Xcode versions.

Comment: I see, thanks anyway. I know we can't discuss unreleased Xcode versions, but what about lldb? ;)

Comment: I'm on Xcode 4.6.2 (which has LLDB 179.5) and I'm still seeing this problem. I've tried redefining _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY to be noinline, but that causes build errors (and probably makes debug performance horrible). Does anyone have any new ideas on workarounds for this? It's making debugging really painful.

Comment: Hm, with Xcode 4.6 this should be working pretty well if the debug info is well formed. You're using clang, right? Are you debugging code that was compiled with an older version of clang?  Xcode 4.6 had a number of improvements to lldb's inlined code stepping support and just as importantly, some improvements to clang's debug info for the same. It's a little hard to remember exactly where things stood at the time Xcode 4.6 was released but on the whole I believe it should be working properly. (I'm sure there are isolated cases where it doesn't - aka bugs), but it shouldn't be a common issue.)