# Xcode Objective-C equivalent of visual studio's [DebuggerHidden] attribute

Tags: objective-c, debugging, xcode5

In visual studio, when programming with C# (or other .NET languages), one can apply an attribute to a method which causes the debugger to ignore it. `[DebuggerHidden]` or `[DebuggerStepThrough]` both allow this in C#.

Is there an equivalent when working with Objective-C code using Xcode 5?

---

Example to illustrate the behaviour

```
void Main() {
    Print("GetNumber returns: ", GetNumber());
}

[DebuggerHidden]
int GetNumber() {
    return 42;
}

void Print(string s, int n) {
    Console.WriteLine(s + n.ToString());
}
```

Without the `[DebuggerHidden]` attribute, when stepping through the code using "Step Into...", control flow goes like this:

1. Main
2. GetNumber
3. Print

With the attribute, the debugger skips GetNumber, and goes straight from Main to Print.
This is very useful for ignoring trivial method calls such as property getters, etc.

I have some various such trivial methods that I'd like to make the debugger skip past in Xcode if possible.

Comment: You can always step over instead of step in when you want to skip something. I know it's not the same, but it works.

Comment: Also not the same, but you can tell lldb to automatically not step into certain functions, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13213341/1187415.